# Is there a click behavior for a list?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I have a list view, on a panoramic control. I've also created an event for MouseLeftButtonUp however I find that when scrolling between the panorama items the MousLeftButtonUp is triggering (it makes sense why but it is unexpected from a user perspective).

Is there any way to create a click event for a list? Or add a behavior that simulates that?

Comment: FYI WP7 use Silverlight 3, not 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checkout the Tap gesture from the Gesture service that's part of the toolkit.

[WP7 Tip of the Day: Silverlight Toolkit: Gestures](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/11/01/WP7-Tip-of-the-Day-Silverlight-Toolkit-Gestures.aspx)

```
    <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,186,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" >
        <Controls:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <Controls:GestureListener Tap="GestureListener_Tap">
            </Controls:GestureListener>
        </Controls:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <ListBoxItem Content="1"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="2"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="3"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="4"/>
    </ListBox>
```

and

```
public void GestureListener_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("tap");
}
```

Comment: I had to use <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
<toolkit:GestureListener  Tap="GestureListener_Tap"/> but it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The listbox should already accept contact, so you can just fire the SelectionChanged event

Comment: This is true, however it won't fire on a second tap if there is no change in selection. This is usually what prompts people to go looking for other options like adding buttons, checking mouseleftbuttonup, etc.