# Selected Item in ListBox gray out after returning from other page

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have two pages : P1 and P2.

In P1,

a) Loading data from IsolatedStorage and DataBinding to listBox1 take place in Button click event in P1.

b) user select an item and be navigated to P2

example : user select  CarModel_1

in P2:
user press Back Key in P2  to return to P1.

The problem :

When returnning from P2, the Selected Item in ListBox1 becomes gray out or Not clickable to go to P2.

example : CarModel_1 becomes gray out or Not clickable.

The rest is clickable.

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way around this problem is to set SelectedIndex = -1 for the listbox.

You can see this in action if you create a default Databound project.

This is the code that is produced.

```
private void MainListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
    if (MainListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

    // Navigate to the new page
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + MainListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

    // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
    MainListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

The alternative to this is to implement the gesture service as outlined in this question.

[Is there a click behavior for a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637793/is-there-a-click-behavior-for-a-list/4637818#4637818)

Comment: @Mick N: Do you know why this behavior happens if you don't reset the selection? I'm curious ...

Comment: Yea, it won't fire SelectionChanged if there is no "change". What would be ideal is a click/tap event as well, but this seems to be unavailable on a lot of controls (except Button). At least there's a few reasonable ways around it.

Comment: @Mick N : Thank you. It seems working now. I will check for a few conditions on ListBox.